# Need Script to find server activation status

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, wmic

We have an environment with different domains and forests with and without trusts.

I need to manage the license for these with out KMS.

I want to find out the servers which are running without activated or with Grace period.

I have been trying with differnt scripts from WMIC and Powershell. But, not able to generate with clear and clean.

Below are the scripts tried. I need assistance on this.

From WMIC:

```
WMIC /Output:@D:\output.txt /node:@D:\serverslist.txt PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE "ProductKeyID like '%-%' AND Description like '%Windows%'" get LicenseStatus
```

From Powershell:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct |where PartialProductKey |select PScomputername,LicenseStatus
```

I need help to generate a table with computer name/IP and license status.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.windowspowershell.aspx) you can create psobject then plus column and value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, I just made a few tweaks.

For one, your code returns the LicenseStatus as a number...which is OK, but to get some real wow-factor, I consulted [this chart from MSDN on what the numbers mean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc534596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and used that with a Switch Statement, within a Calulated Property to replace the number with the human-meaningful license status, giving us logic like this:

```
select Pscomputername,Name,@{Name='LicenseStatus';Exp={

switch ($_.LicenseStatus)
{
0 {'Unlicensed'}
1 {'licensed'}
2 {'OOBGrace'}
3 {'OOTGrace'}
4 {'NonGenuineGrace'}
5 {'Notification'}
6 {'ExtendedGrace'}
Default {'Undetected'}
}
#EndofCalulatedProperty
}}
```

This gives us full code, like this, and also extracts the name of the product as well.  You can run this against multiple systems by just adding their names to the -ComputerName property:

```
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct -computerName localhost,dc01,windows10 |
     where PartialProductKey | select Pscomputername,Name,@{Name='LicenseStatus';Exp={
        switch ($_.LicenseStatus)
        {
    0 {'Unlicensed'}
    1 {'licensed'}
    2 {'OOBGrace'}
    3 {'OOTGrace'}
    4 {'NonGenuineGrace'}
    5 {'Notification'}
    6 {'ExtendedGrace'}
    Default {'Undetected'}
}
#EndOfCaltulatedProperty
}}
```

This gives you results like this:

```
PSComputerName                         Name                                   LicenseStatus                        
--------------                         ----                                   -------------                        
localhost                              Office 15, OfficeProPlusVL_MAK edition licensed                             
localhost                              Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition   licensed 
dc01                                   Windows(R), ServerStandard edition     licensed
Windows10                              Windows(R), ServerStandard edition     licensed
```

Comment: This script is perfect and great, however am not able to run for remote machines and with IP address due to the recrictions set in WINRM. Am Just fighting with it to get it fixed. will update you once i get it fixed. Thanks

Comment: If you want to run this in your whole environment, you'll need to turn on PowerShell remoting.  There are group policys you can use for the whole company, or you can do a single PC at a time with 'Enable-PSRemoting -Force' from the Admin PowerShell prompt

Comment: I have tried many things from enabling psremoting, enabling Https in winrm by creating self signed and assigned cert's, enabling trusted list to all. Not able to get through it. Planning to run on individual domains with domain credentials just as you did and will update you... Thanks

Comment: I was having similar talk on Scripting Guy too, got the workaround. Please check the link.. Thanks a lot for your help and time.   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/3579ba4f-a9d5-45f3-b80e-fdfc7dafafc2/need-script-to-find-server-activation-status?forum=ITCG

Answer (score 1):

you may also try

```
$activation      = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct | where ApplicationId -EQ 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f | where PartialProductKey).LicenseStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct | 
where PartialProductKey | 
select Name, ApplicationId, LicenseStatus
```